Error 403 coming from nowhere
We have a Linux server hosting 2 vhosts: preprod and prod.
We tested for a few weeks a python script as a cron job on the preprod side before deploying it to the prod vhost: this script call a PHP API on that same server using requests.post(). It was time last week to go prod but it doesn't go as planned...
We don't have any problem calling the API:

On the preprod vhost from the python script on the same machine
On the prod vhost from Insomnia (an API test application used to send customs HTTP requests) on another machine

However, when calling the prod vhost API from the python script running on the server itself, we always get a 403 error with a default HTML error page.
The request doesn't reach PHP, so I checked files owner and group and also the rights on the files.
The strange part is that there is nothing in the access.log file nor the error.log file event using the INFO log level (access.log successfully shows requests that reach PHP), then I tried to trace the request: I modified the ErrorDocument instructions adding a little difference for each vhost (even the default one) and check each one using various requests. I got the modified 403 errors when another computer requests, but not from localhost requesting prod vhost. I really don't know where that 403 html error page come from as it's not event the default one from Apache.
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE></HEAD>

Thank you for your help.

Middle box. What does your packet capture on the host and the endpoint show?

Also the test environment differs in a fundamental way that effectively renders it not useful.

Production data are copied to preprod environment twice a day and code is updated on preprod only a few hours prior to production as their is already to test stages before it.
That's why I don't understand the difference.
